# how to add a value from one array of elements to another using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to add the values from an array of elements type select/input and place the values using a for loop to an array type div and place the value as an inner html.here is my code:

```
var inputAndSelectArray = document.getElementsByClassName("selectAndInputStyle");
for (i = 0; i < inputAndSelectArray.length; i++) {
    inputAndSelectArray[i].style.display = "none";
    var text = inputAndSelectArray[i].value;
    var parent = inputAndSelectArray[i].parentNode;
    var displayDiv = parent.getElementsByClassName("divDisplayInfo");
    displayDiv[i].innerHTML = text[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `html` please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work, you just need to remove

```
displayDiv[i].innerHTML =text[i] ;
// this ---------------------^^^
```

E.g.:

```
displayDiv[i].innerHTML =text ;
```

`text` is the value, not an array of values. You got the value from the form control array:

```
var text = inputAndSelectArray[i].value;
```

So no need to index into it with `[i]` again.

---

That said, since you're looking for `.divDisplayInfo` *within* the parent element of the input, you may not want to use `[i]`; you may just want the first (perhaps only) matching div. So either:

```
parent.getElementsByClassName("divDisplayInfo")[0].innerHTML = text;
```

or

```
parent.querySelector(".divDisplayInfo").innerHTML = text;
```

*(`querySelector` returns the first element matching the given CSS selector. If you just want the first matching element, no need to get the full list.)*

We'd have to see your HTML to be sure about that, though.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are using: `inputAndSelectArray.length` as the loop limit but does `displayDiv` has the same length?

2) Getting the selected text of a 'Select' object goes like this: `element.options[element.selectedIndex];` Where `element` is the 'Select' object.

3) `text` is not an array, so no need for the `[i]`.

More code/information will help, since it looks a little messy.